# How to implement this below code in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

```
   $(document).on("click", ".toggle-row-handler", function(event) {
            var $this = $(this),
                parent = $this.closest("tr");
            $this.toggleClass("active"), parent.next().toggleClass("open")
        })
```

how to implement this code snippet in angular js as I have to toggle a  on click of a css.

Comment: Give your problem statement. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

With Angular, you can listen for click events on HTML elements using the ng-click directive, and dynamically set the class using ng-class IE:

```
<table ng-click="triggerFunction()" ng-class="class"></i>
```

So in the controller you could have a function that sets the class variable:

```
 $scope.changeClass = function( element ){
          if (element .class === "inactive")
            element.class = "active";
            element.parent.class = "open";
          else
            element.class = "inactive";
            element.parent.class = "closed";
        };
```

Now how you bind the elements to their class variables would really depend on the implementation. Since it looks like you are dealing with a table, maybe you have an array of data stored in this table that is set using ng-repeat to generate rows.

Here is an example with that assumption in mind: 
https://jsfiddle.net/pWG2S/1050/

NOTE: My example assumes that the table will not be rearranged and will always be displayed in order of the array. If you were to use other Angular features such as allowing the order to change or filtering, this would probably no longer fit the use case. (Assuming the use case is to change the class of the element, and the element directly above.)